# Directory Enumerate to skip folder

Tags: c#

I have this lovely bit of code that does a brilliant job for me, just grabs all the files I need for multiple searches etc.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
                    .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)));
}
```

However there is one folder that I do not need the report to show in one of my directories. We'll call the folder "Narnia". I know there is a `Directory.Skip` but I am not entirely sure how to use it.

The command that calls the GetFiles(); is below. It just write out the returned list to a txt file. I wonder could I filter it from there?

```
internal static void GetFilesPassThrough(string SearchRoot, string extensions, string savepath) //GetFiles Regex Thread Start. 
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in GetFiles(SearchRoot, extensions))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savepath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(file);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + savepath);
    }
}
```

## Additional Information

As James has requested I will provide more in depth of how the code is called.

*Button is pressed which calls the GetFilesPassThrough(SearchDirectory, Extensions, savepath)
   * Extensions being what files I need reporting out of a directory, .PDF, .txt, .xls etc
   * As you can see above in the GetFilesPassThrough code, it Try's the GetFile() and returns each string called back in the List.

**Button > GetFilesPassThrough> Creates list with Get Files> And writes to textfile **

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I think you will need to write your own method to traverse all subdirectories recursively and ignore the one(s) called "Narnia", as `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is not very configurable AFAIK (it only lets you specify "only this folder" or "all subfolders" but nothing in between). Here's a [RosettaCode task](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C.23) that may get you started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you're looking to hard code a magic string somewhere or pass in via some sort of params, but you could do something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(
    string path, string searchPatternExpression = "",
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
    params string[] toIgnore)
{
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
                    .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)))
                    .Where(file => !toIgnore.Contains(file));
}
```

(Of course this is simplistic, if you care about casing, but should be a start.)

**Edit**

If you want a case-insensitive search, you could change it to look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(
    string path, string searchPatternExpression = "",
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
    params string[] toIgnore)
{
    var hash = new HashSet<string>(toIgnore, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
                    .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)))
                    .Where(file => !hash.Contains(file));
}
```

**Edit 2**

If you're looking to skip the *directory* with a given name, try:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(
    string path, string searchPatternExpression = "",
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
    params string[] toIgnore)
{
    var hash = new HashSet<string>(toIgnore, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", searchOption)
                    .Where(folder => !hash.Contains(Path.GetDirectoryName(folder)))
                    .SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(x, "*", searchOption));
}
```

Note that this is going to ignore *all* subdirectories that match your ignore set.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks it seems like thats the way to go. So I am calling the method by `GetFiles(SearchRoot, extensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories, "Narnia")` However, it still comes up in my report, and also `file.Name` does not compile. Any thoughts?

Comment: Whoops, that was supposed to just be `!toIgnore.Contains(file))`. Also, if you need it to be case insensitive, you have to do a little more work (I can show an example if needed). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi James, that hasn't worked either unfortunately. I have entered it as the folder shows in my directory.

Comment: Ah, you're looking to skip a *directory* named "Narnia"?

Comment: Hi James, even that hasn't worked, and to simplify things i have tried just doing this :   `public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles2(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            var hash = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            hash.Add("Narnia");` I have attempted to modify the code so the stream writer doesn't catch is, as the file has gone from a 200kb report, to a 900kb report. it seems to be doing the work twice.

Comment: Can you give a visual layout of what you're trying to do in your question? I feel like there is some sort of disconnect where I may be trying to solve the wrong problem. Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see what is going on in the algorithm to make sure this is the right place to filter out the directory? (And that the call is actually being made to `GetFiles2` instead of what might be the original one?

Comment: I think that its spitting out too much as its returning to the List. I have added additional information for you, and for each iteration you provide I just add a number to the GetFiles, so I have a backup, and can see what each one is up to. I make sure I also change this in the GetFilesPassThrough.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (!(file.Contains("Narnia"))) writer.WriteLine(file)
```

Or am I being too simplistic and misunderstanding?

Comment: the way I understand it, OP does not want to skip files called "Narnia". He wants to Directory.EnumerateFiles to recurse in all subdirectories except for a folder called "Narnia"

Comment: Hey Craig Thanks for the handy help, but Paolo is right :) I don't need the folder.